# twig code in js file

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

Using symfony2 with twig templates, I normally use js embedded inside the `*html.twig` file to dinamize yet more the pages.

What if I have external JS files attached to my page? How could I introduce twig code inside them?

I know it sounds sort of wears, but it is not that much when trying to redirect from javascript to a known symfony path. Just like this:

```
$.post("{{ path('_check_coupon') }}",{code: coupon_code}, function(json) {
    // do whatever...
});
```

As you can see, I have in a complete separated js file an ajax call to a known path `"_check_coupon"`.

Any idea to approach this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either embed such path in a `data-path` attribute in a DOM element, like:

```
<div id="widget" data-path="{{ path('_check_coupon') }}"> ... </div>
```

Then just fetch it:

```
$.post( $('#widget').data('path') ,{code: coupon_code}, function(json) {
    // do whatever...
});
```

That's a vanilla approach, yet more maintainable that having both js and twig mixed in a single file - at least you won't get syntax highlight.

Of course if you are dealing with forms, just fetch form's `action` attribute.

---

Anyway I advise you not to have both JS and markup on the same page: you won't be able to cache scripts, nor to minify them, so consider decoupling them unless it's just very very few lines involved. Feel free to check [my little library about](http://moonwave99.github.com/simple.js/).

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is old but I came across the same problem and found the following solution by using the [`verbatim`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/verbatim.html) tag.

```
// {% verbatim %}
(function() {
// {% endverbatim %}
    var val = "{{ myImportVar|raw }}";
// {% verbatim %}

    /**
     * JS Code
     */
     console.log(val);
}());
// {% endverbatim %}
```

Ive wrapped them in JS comments to make my editor hints etc. working.